# Rhino: how to make Rhino evaluate a RegEx expression on a Java String?

Tags: javascript, java, regex, replace, rhino

I have trouble calling `.replace(searchValue, newValue)` on Java String objects from Rhino when `searchValue` is a RegEx expression. This works otherwise fine when `searchValue` is not a RegEx expression, or when the method is called on a String which was initiated from within JavaScript.

Example:

Sample Java object and a method that returns a string

```
public class MyTestObject {
    public String returnStringValue() {
        return " This is a string with spaces ";
    }
}
```

Set up of Rhino, creation of the Java object

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.script.*;

public class TestRhino{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException {
        // Create my Java Object
        MyTestObject testObject = new MyTestObject();

        // Initiate the JavaScript engine
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript");
        Compilable compEngine = (Compilable)engine;

        // evaluate my JavaScript file; add my Java object to it
        engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader("MyJavaScriptFile.js"));
        engine.put("testObject", testObject); // this adds my Java Object to Rhino

        // Invoke my javaScript function
        Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
        Object returnVal = inv.invokeFunction("testFunction");

        // print out the result
        System.out.println(returnVal); // should print "ThisisaString" to the console
    }
}
```

My JavaScript function (this code **cannot** be modified in any way).

```
function testFunction() {
    let myString = testObject.returnStringValue();
    return myString.replace(/\s/g,"");  // Error!
}
```

This throws an error `The choice of Java constructor replace matching JavaScript argument types (function,string) is ambiguous; candidate constructors are: class java.lang.String replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)`.

However, when my JavaScript function is modified as follows, Rhino returns the expected value, and no error is thrown.

```
function testFunction() {
    let myString = testObject.returnStringValue();
    return myString.replace("T", "P"); //  Phis is a string with spaces 
}
```

The following JavaScript function also works when it is called with Rhino.

```
function testFunction() {
    return " This is a string with spaces ".replace(/\s/g,""); // Thisisastringwithspaces
}
```

I'm looking for a way to make the above works without modifying the JavaScript code. I can only modify the Java code.

Note: this works well with Nashorn (default JavaScript engine from Java1.8 onwards), however I have to use Rhino (default javaScript engine until Java 1.7).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the Java code calls

```
replace(null, null);
```

method in the [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class and thus does not know, if it should execute -

```
replace(char oldChar, char newChar);
```

or

```
replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement);
```

Cast the arguments in the Java call to:

```
replace((CharSequence) null, (CharSequence) null);
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems plausible, however since `.replace(val1, val2)` is called from the JavaScript code (and not from the Java code), I am not sure how I can solve this issue. I have tried changing the return value of returnStringValue() to CharSequence but it resulted in the same issue